# I don’t like that smell. / That smells unpleasant to me

Tags: sentence-meaning

> I don’t like that smell.
>
> That smells bad/unpleasant to me.

As I understand it, the meaning of these sentences are absolutely interchangeable. Right? In this case "bad" is "not good", or even worse than "unpleasant"?

Comment: @Lambie, What's the need to write this? You can do your business. Don't stop me from learning English.

Comment: The reason is because you're not supposed to ask questions that can be answered with dictionary searches.

Comment: @FeliniusRex, Could you tell me a dictionary that explains sentences?

Comment: It's not the sentence that's the issue -- it's the equivalence of "smells bad" and "don't like...smell".

Comment: @FeliniusRex, That is demagogy.

Comment: Uhm, ok. I thought it was clear-cut applying what the [tour] says. It's not personal. I didn't mean any offense.

Comment: _That smell_ could be something you can smell in the air, of unknown origin. **That** _smells bad_ probably refers to a particular object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - (1) I don’t like that smell.
> - (2) That smells bad/unpleasant to me.

In many cases the meaning of the two sentences will be essentially the same. In those cases, (1) will be more casual, but also more visceral, expressing more clearly  a personal, individual reaction than (2) does.

However, there is at least one additional sense in which (1) could be used where (2) would not fit. The sentence (1) could be used to mean "That smell makes me suspicious." For example:

> - I don’t like that smell. I think there is a short circuit in that assembly.
> - I don’t like that smell. I think this dish may have spoiled.
> - I don’t like that smell. We must change it or the restaurant will lose business.

In addition to literal uses like the above, this sense may be used when "smell" is metaphorical.

> - I don't like the smell of this. I think someone is taking bribes.

A "bad smell" can be used to mean a sensation without proof of something amiss, often some sort of wrongdoing or "foul play". Variations on (1) are much more likely to be used in this way than are variations on (2).

Thus I conclude that while there is a large overlap in meaning between (1) and (2), they are not interchangeable in all cases.

Comment: Could you tell me, in that context, "That smells unpleasant" is worse than "That smells bad", right?

Comment: @Sergei I wouldn't describe either as "worse". "That smells bad is more personal, as well as more casual. Either might be used for a very bad or a more moderate smell, quite aside from the metaphoric uses.